# Replace key in find_or_create_by by a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
  def my_model
    MyModel.find_or_create_by(my_model_id: id)
  end
```

This code is working, but because I am moving it into a mixin, my_model_id should be a variable. For that I created the following method

```
  def attribute_name_for_relation
    (self.class.name.downcase + "_id").to_sym
  end
```

`MyModel.find_or_create_by(attribute_name_for_relation: id)` won't work however of course.

Is there a way by which I can replace `my_model_id:` by a dynamic variable?

Comment: Generating the column name of an identifier by its class name and the `_id` suffix, feels to me like your associations are not set up properly. And that this is a xy problem. Would you mind explaining why you need to generate the column name dynamically? What is you use case?

Comment: As an aside `self.class.name.downcase` will only work if your classes are a single word or you intend to break convention. Instead I would recommend `self.class.name.underscore`. Additionally in ruby we don't generally concatenate strings using `String#+` instead it would be more idiomatic to use interpolation `"#{self.class.name.underscore}_id".to_sym`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `MyModel.find_or_create_by(attribute_name_for_relation => id)`

(`attribute_name_for_relation:` is a symbol and not a call to your method)

Comment: To expand on this, this is called the "hashrocket" syntax and it's what you have to use when you need the keys to be _anything_ other than symbols.